# Inserting values from one table into specific fields in another table in SQLite3

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have a feeling this is a simple error, but I do not know what I am doing wrong! I have one table in sqlite3 that has 33 fields, called "users" and want to import data for 7 of the fields from another table.

Here is what I am doing:

```
INSERT INTO users(id, username, password, firstName, lastName, email, membershipStart) SELECT(id, username, password, nicename, displayname, email, registered) FROM tempUSERS;
```

And then I get:

```
Error: near ",": syntax error
```

What is wrong with what I am doing??
-Raymosrunerx

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the parens in the `select`:

```
INSERT INTO users(id, username, password, firstName, lastName, email, membershipStart)
    SELECT id, username, password, nicename, displayname, email, registered
    FROM tempUSERS;
```

When the SQL parser encounters parentheses, it is expecting a scalar expression or subquery.  Your expression is clearly not a subquery, and commas are not appropriate in a scalar expression.